# Currency Format in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to show my numbers in money format and separate digits like the example below:

1000 -----> 1,000

10000 -----> 10,000

100000 -----> 1,00,000

1000000 -----> 10,00,000

100000000 -----> 10,00,00,000

My Currency Local in Bangladesh.

Advanced Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Without currency symbol

```kotlin
val value = 10_000_000
NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale("en", "BD")).format(value)
// outputs: 10,000,000
```

With currency symbol:

```kotlin
val value = 10_000_000
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en-BD", "BD")).format(value)
// outputs: BDT 10,000,000.00
```

Comment: Thank you, But still not working. 

I am use this code:


 NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en-BD", "BD")).format(10_000_000);

Comment: change 10_000_00 to the value you want to change

Comment: @HridoyKrisnaDas I've updated the answer, another question would be, are you using Kotlin or Java?  because the code above is in Kotlin and it returns the formatted string.

Comment: Sorry for that, I am using Java.